# Chrome tab for Twitter shows new tweet count; any way just to show notification count?

Tags: twitter, google-chrome

When I have Twitter open in desktop Chrome, the tab label will display a counter of all of the new tweets in my feed. This isn't at all helpful since I'm not interested in re-checking Twitter every 30 seconds. I wish the counter would render my notification count, like a Facebook tab does. Is this at all possible? Otherwise would it be possible to disable the counter from rendering?

It may seem like a very minor issue, but I find my Gmail and Facebook tab counters to be useful, but the Twitter counter to be a distraction. (After a period of time, the new tweet count will get high enough, maybe 25 or so, and the counter is replaced by a constant asterisk, which I'm glad to see. Sure, if I followed more accounts, I'd reach the asterisk faster).

[image: Chrome tab Twitter count]

[image: Chrome tab Twitter count after many new tweets]